# How to check that a process is running on windows with zabbix

Tags: windows, zabbix

What would be the correct way to test that a specific process* is running on a host machine running Windows 7 that is connected to zabbix server?

After [reading](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys) a bit I understood using the `proc_info` item is what I need, and I figured testing that the physical memory is more than zero would be correct and so I tried the following trigger:

`{HOST_NAME:proc_info[TestProcess.exe,wkset,sum].last(0,0)}<1`

But this gives an error:

> Evaluation failed for function {HOST_NAME:proc_info[TestProcess.exe,wkset,sum].last(0,0)}<1

What is the problem with my trigger? Or maybe there's a better item I can define?

*(the prcess is supposed to run all the time, mostly idle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to correct this by fixing the trigger function to `last(#1)` because `last()` takes 2 arguments with the second being *time_shift* and optional. Here, I don't need a time shift but the latest possible value, so I removed it.

The first argument here is the selection of **which** last value, so here I need the last one, with the number sign to indicate the last value that was taken and not the last value from some seconds ago.

The full trigger is:

```
{HOST_NAME:proc_info[TestProcess.exe,wkset,min].last(#1)}<1
```

The comparison here is in KBytes and I changed the ***`type`*** in the *proc_info* to *`min`* just to robust the condition in case I have multiple processes with the same name.
When this is true the trigger is executed and I'll know there's a problem with the process.

Comment: You can also consider using item `proc.num[TestProcess.exe]`.

Comment: Can't +1 yet but that suites my situation better.